# Combine awk with sub to print multiple columns

Tags: awk

Input:

```
MARKER  POS EA  NEA BETA    SE  N   EAF STRAND  IMPUTED
1:244953:TTGAC:T 244953 T TTGAC -0.265799 0.291438 4972 0.00133176 + 1
2:569406:G:A 569406 A G -0.17456 0.296652 4972 0.00128021 + 1
```

Desired output:

```
1 1:244953:TTGAC:T 0 244953
2 2:569406:G:A 0 569406
```

Column 1 in output file is first number from first column in input file

Tried:

```
awk '{gsub(/:.*/,"",$1);print $1,0,$2}' input
```

But it does not print `$2` correctly

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is right, but the reason it didn't work is that you've replaced the `$1` value as part of the `gsub()` routine and have *not* backed it up. So next call to `$1` will return the value after the call. So back it up as below. Also `sub()` is sufficient here for the first replacement part

```
awk 'NR>1{backup=$1; sub(/:.*/,"",backup);print backup,$1,0,$2}' file
```

Or use `split()` function to the first part of the first column. The call to the function returns the number of elements split by delimiter `:` and updates the elements to the array `a`. We print the element and subsequent columns as needed.

```
awk 'NR>1{n=split($1, a, ":"); print a[1],$1,"0", $2}' file
```

From GNU `awk` documentation under [String functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions)

#### `split(string, array [, fieldsep [, seps ] ])`

> Divide string into pieces separated by `fieldsep` and store the pieces in array and the separator strings in the `seps` array. The first piece is stored in `array[1]`, the second piece in `array[2]`, and so forth. The string value of the third argument, `fieldsep`, is a regexp describing where to split string.

Add a `| column -t` to beautify the result to make it appear more spaced out and readable

```
awk 'NR>1{n=split($1, a, ":"); print a[1],$1,"0", $2}' file | column -t
```

Comment: thank you it worked! Could you add some explanation about split command, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you?

```
awk -v s1=" " -F"[: ]" 'FNR>1{print $1 s1 $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4 s1 "0" s1 $5}' OFS=":"   Input_file
```